# How to make complex query when using "hibernate filter"?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, acl

I and my colleague are working to make a framework for our company.
We are using Hibernate as DAO and Spring as IOC.
We would like to use hibernate filters to reduce our result set based on some restrictions, but we are confused how to use it properly!

Consider entity A has reference to B and B to C and C to D ant etc...
How can we write a filter that when i search the A entity, all the filters defined on B, C and D applied.

We have used Hibernate filters in very cases but we have not already succeeded in such these cases.
Have we got any other solutions for filtering data ?

Comment: why not start by saying what is a "Hibernate filter" ? You mean a JPQL query? If you really mean a Hibernate extension called "Hibernate filter" then please untag "JPA" from this question since that is not part of the JPA API

Comment: No JPQL and i removed the JPA tag;)

Comment: Nobody is here to answer me? Is it really so difficult?

Answer (score 0):

I stuck into similar problem recently. The only solution I've found is to write a full SQL with all conditions which you need and retrieve all IDs of A (if we're creating a filter in the A entity) which matches your requirements and then in the filter check, whether ID is in those IDs or not. It would be something like

```
@FilterDef(name = "filterName", 
           parameters = {@ParamDef(name = "param", type = "string")},
           defaultCondition = "id in (select a.id from A a
                                      join B b on a.b_id = b.id
                                      join C c on b.c_id = c.id
                                      where c.some_property = 2)")
```

However, I'm not sure this is a good solution for some large queries.